# Creating and Deploying a Custom Login Page for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part, custom-form

I want created a custom login page .

I use this [link](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1093&page=1) for created custom login .

But when i build the solution,don't create a folder inside .\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\CustomLoginPageFBA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have followed the steps correctly, it should work.

Make sure that, once you have created the application page, the solution explorer structure looks like this -

[image]

Deploying this will create the folder and files for you inside the "Layouts" folder.

Comment: Ok Thanks , But when go to Central Administration.Select Site from Application Management.Click on Authentication Provider.Select Zone but have not  Sign In Page URL Section
for Change Custom Sign In Page URL.

Comment: Make sure that you have selected "Claims Authentication" instead of Classic Mode Authentication, while you create a web application.