# Can we create a Custom login page in Sharepoint foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Can we create a Custom login page in Sharepoint foundation 2010? If its possible can you explain how can we done it.

Comment: This question is a DUPLICATE.
Please refer to this link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33986/creating-and-deploying-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010

Comment: His main concern is can he do this in SharePoint Foundation 2010, not the method itself..

Comment: Thank you. But i want to know is it possible in foundation version.